# Can i exe a file from mac that runs on MS Win server?

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu

This is the current situation: 1 MS Windows Software, 4 different rooms and 8 different machines, so organized:

- Room 1: 2x Ubuntu, 1x Mac
- Room 2: 3x Mac
- Room 3: 2x Ubuntu

Each person needs the same software that runs on MS Windows only, so we have the option of buying the single license for each PC or the server license.

If we choose to get the server type license and we install it on a local MS Windows Server 2019 can i execute it from all the PCs? In other words, is it possible to install the software on the server and create some kind of symlink on all the desktop/laptop that need to access the software?

Comment: You cannot directly run Windows software on MACs or Ubuntu.

Comment: @DavidPostill: There's always WINE, but their software needs to be tested & verified.

Comment: You can get RDS (Terminal services) licences for the Windows Server 2019. So that 8 clients can concurrently connect to the Win Server using RDP - remote desktop, and run the app. Of course it costs more, RDS licences, plus probably more memory and CPU on server to handle the load.

Comment: @harrymc That's why I said "directly"

Comment: Knowing what the software is may make the answers & comments more accurate. For some kind of 'officey' app, wine or similar might work, for a heavy 3D renderer… unlikely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use
[Wine](https://www.winehq.org/)
defined as:

> Wine (originally an acronym for "Wine Is Not an Emulator") is a compatibility layer capable of running Windows applications on several POSIX-compliant operating systems, such as Linux, macOS, & BSD. Instead of simulating internal Windows logic like a virtual machine or emulator, Wine translates Windows API calls into POSIX calls on-the-fly, eliminating the performance and memory penalties of other methods and allowing you to cleanly integrate Windows applications into your desktop.

For legal reasons, you would need a license for every computer where the Windows
software is installed.

If you would like to only buy one license for the Windows Server, some possibilities
would be:

- Use some Remote Desktop (RDP) software so each client can connect to the
  server and have its own desktop. Microsoft's RDP for that many clients needs buying
  enough Terminal Server Remote Desktop Client Access Licenses (CALs).
- Publish the application from the server using an product such as the free
  [WinConn](https://stanev.org/winconn/)
  that leverages
  [RemoteApp technology](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-security-and/introducing-remoteapp-and-desktop-connections/ba-p/246803).
  Another free possibility is
  [RemoteApp on Github](https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP/wiki/RemoteApp).